# Insert operators into 3 5 7 = 7

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

How can you insert any math symbol/operation () ! - + x / square root etc into 3 5 7 = 7 without adding any numbers or changing the order? For example, 3-7+5=1 or 3+7-5=5.
Also, try to solve 3 7 5 = 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  What order did you want: 357 or 375?

Comment: Oh yeah :( bruh my answer is now completely wrong...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PSE! We don't usually do "any math symbol" puzzles here, because that enables too many possible solutions (including outright silly ones), which turns the question into a popularity contest, and that isn't the purpose of this site. Cheers, and happy posting!

Answer (score 5):

If you mean $3, 5, 7$:

> $\sqrt{3!+5-7}=2$, $3!/(-5+7)=3$, $3!+5-7=4$, $3\cdot(-5+7)=6$, $(3!-5)\cdot7=7$, $3!-5+7=8$, $-3+5+7=9$, and I can't think of a good one for $10$, but I do have the bizarre: (drumroll please)

> $((3!)!/5!)!\cdot7!=10!$ !!!

If you mean $3, 7, 5$:

> $\sqrt{3!-7+5}=2$, $3!/(7-5)=3$, $3!-7+5=4$, $3\cdot(7-5)=6$, $\sqrt{-3+7}+5=7$, $3!+7-5=8$, $-3+7+5=9$, $\sqrt{-3+7}\cdot5=10$.